# Communication between two channel in hyperledger fabric is possible?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am new in blockchain development. I hosted a hyper ledger composer on two PC(Local computers).

Then

I created composer channels in PC1.

I created composerchannel1 in PC2.

I used same crypto materials for both PC1 and PC2. I need to set up a communication between two channel. I searched much time on google. But no document is founded regarding this topic. If Anyone has any idea about this topic, then Please give the answer.

OS:Ubuntu 16.04
Fabric:1.1.0
composer:0.19.15

Thanks in advance..!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Fabric uses channels as a form of isolation, so joining channels is not a normal activity.

Composer starts and runs a Business Network on a single channel specified in the connection.json file of the Business network card.

If you start the same Business Network on a different channel it will be separate and the 2 versions of the network will not communicate.

It is possible to use the `getNativeAPI` feature in Composer to connect directly to a 2nd network, but this is specifically written code to write to both Networks rather than the 2 Networks and Channels connecting directly.  There is a [tutorial example](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/invoke-composer-network) of connecting to 2 networks.

Comment: I think this tutorials is in  single network. I have two network in seperate machine. And i created one channel for each network. I need to communicate with both channel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, limited support for cross-channel queris via 'InvokeChaincode' API is possible. Check https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L66.

Ref: https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/message/1169

Comment: I have two network in seperate machine. And i created one channel for each network. I need to communicate with both channel .Have any idea about it . Please share me....